# Correct use of exclamation mark in 'wham wham wham'

Tags: exclamation-mark

Please let me know in which of the two sentences below the exclamation mark is used correctly:

> 1. I then slapped the fisherman three times, wham, wham, wham!
> 2. I then slapped the fisherman three times, wham! wham! wham!

Comment: I then punched the fisherman three times ... Wham! Wham! Wham! // 'Wham' is used as a _sentence substitute_ (no subject or verb, but conveying a complete idea) and may be punctuated as a sentence. The staccato effect of the three interjections is ideal in not-too-formal writing.